# google chrome extension manifest loading jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load the jquery in the manifest's content_scripts but when I load a page with also a jquery already loaded in their page the dropdown stops working for some reason and I can't find any error in my console log. So if I removed the jquery in my manifest's content_scripts the dropdown works just fine that is why I assume that is because the  current page that I already have loaded the jquery library.

```
"content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": ["js/jquery-2.2.4.js", "js/custom.js"],
    }],
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment): "Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page. ". The page's jQuery cant interfere with your content scripts. There must be more going on here. What exactly is your extension doing?

Comment: Please also provide what is `custom.js` doing

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Chrome has a builtin debugger where you can see exactly what's happening inside your content script instead of guessing.

Comment: Can you define more precisely what you mean by "dropdown stops working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content Script runs on different js context than main window, so they mustn't conflict at all.

You may also try remove your jQuery from window context scope by executing:

```
var myJquery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

But you need move your script to document_start for this have effect by adding to your manifest file script_context section:

```
"content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": ["js/jquery-2.2.4.js", "js/custom.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }]
```

But if you do it, your custom.js script must be ready to execute on state when document is not ready yet.

If you attach more sources, it would be more relevant solution.